# Mootools drop down menu drop downward not upward

Tags: html, css, mootools

I am looking at the code for this drop slide down menu like this one.

http://www.andrewsellick.com/examples/tabslideV2-mootools/

But i am unsure how to make it expand downwards the opposite way assuming the links are on top?

Comment: For a start that link uses mootools not jQuery ....

Comment: Oops i got confused there -__--

Comment: you really should take out the code for this and post it + mock it on jsfiddle - if you want somebody to (help) reverse it for you.

Comment: As @DimitarChristoff said - give it your best shot on jsFiddle, or post on there what you've accomplished so far. The best way to learn js/mootools is to actually try to do it, instead of copying an already working answer.

Comment: this was written for mootools 1.11 and really badly written. nobody will bother converting it as is. look at it: http://www.andrewsellick.com/examples/tabslideV2-mootools/js/tabslide.js - reliance on global variables and hardwired Ids, accessing element properties directly, function-based - this is NOT good mootools code. having said that, changing it will be trivial.

Comment: mystycs, Was going to post a "fix" from the file that Dimitar linked to, but I am in agreement that you would be better off jumping to the latestes v1.4.0 of mooTools. If you confirm that this is OK I will knockout a quick class for you and walk you through implementing it.

Comment: very first simple fix .panel_container { top:0; } it will work like menu

Answer (score 0):

As others have said without a JSFiddle example it's a bit hard to help.
Maybe this is closer to what you're looking for as far as animated drop down. The one you provided has a lot of unnecessary code in there. Hope it helps.

[JavaScript drop down menu using Mootools 1.2](http://www.php-help.ro/mootools-12-javascript-examples/javascript-drop-down-menu-using-mootools-12/)